# cmake command to read generated config file

Tags: cmake

I have a library compiled and installed, under `${INSTALL_PATH}/share` there is `config.mk` file with content like:

```
MFEM_VERSION           = 40502
MFEM_VERSION_STRING    = 4.5.2
MFEM_SOURCE_DIR        = /home/hbui/sw2/mfem-all/mfem-4.5.2
MFEM_INSTALL_DIR       = /opt/mfem-4.5.2
MFEM_GIT_STRING        = (unknown)
MFEM_USE_MPI           = YES
MFEM_USE_METIS         = YES
MFEM_USE_METIS_5       = YES
MFEM_DEBUG             = NO
```

How can i use `cmake` to read this file to local variables such as `${MFEM_USE_MPI}`, etc?

Comment: read it into CMake variables? What exactly do you mean by "local variables"?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a variable and then use regex to extract data:

```
file(READ ${INSTALL_PATH}/share/config.mk config)

string(REGEX MATCH "MFEM_VERSION[ \t\r\n]*=[ \t\r\n]*(.*)[ \t\r\n]" _ ${config})
set(MFEM_VERSION ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})

string(REGEX MATCH "MFEM_VERSION_STRING[ \t\r\n]*=[ \t\r\n]*(.*)[ \t\r\n]" _ ${config})
set(MFEM_VERSION_STRING ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})

...
```

You can even define a function that accepts a file path and creates all the variables at the parent scope using names pulled from the file.